# WPF Group datagrid by year and nested quarters

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, grouping

I have a collection of `OrderItems` that had a `OrderDate` property of type Date. Now i use the Datagrid Groups to group them by date but this is not exactly what i'm looking for. The thing what i'm trying to create is create the first group by year of OrderDate and then within those groups a group per Quater. So it will end up like:

2020
   Q1
   Q2
   Q3
   Q4

2019
   Q1
   Q2
   Q3
   Q4

2018
   Q1
   Q2
   Q3
   Q4
etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another property to your `OrderItem` class that returns the quarter:

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    public int OrderYear => OrderDate.Year;

    public string Quarter => $"Q{(OrderDate.Month + 2) / 3}";
}
```

And another `PropertyGroupDescription` to the `CollectionView`:

```
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("OrderYear"));
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("OrderQuarter"));
```

If you don't want to or can extend the `OrderItem` class for some reason, this is time to create view model wrappers for your domain types and bind to these. In other words, replace `OrderItem` with an `OrderItemViewModel` and add the properties to the new class.

Comment: Thanks your method works like a charm, sometimes it's that easy! I did change you way of calculating the quarter to `DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter, OrderDate)`